# Match columns of a new and old spreadsheet and then input data into new spreadsheet

Tags: shell-script

I have spreadsheet (spreadsheet A) with multiple columns containing data plus a column at the end containing data with comments.
I have a new spreadsheet (spreadsheet B) with all the same columns of data but the column at the end does not contain any data with comments.

I would like to do the following:

If the IP address in spreadsheet A matches the IP address in spreadsheet B, then add the corresponding comment from spreadsheet A to the comment field in spreadsheet B.

Comment: Do you use flat-file as spreadsheet ?

Comment: can U share a sample data?

Comment: Francois - I use an .xlsx spreadsheet. What format does it need to be in?

Comment: msp9011 - Spreadsheet A Data    
IP  Hostname Status Updated On Comment
IP1 host1 data 05/04/2019 at 11:06:52 This is a device
IP2 host2 data 05/04/2019 at 11:07:15 This is a device
    
Spreadsheet B Data (this is the new spreadsheet)    
IP Hostname Status Updated On Comment
IP1 host1 data 05/04/2019 at 11:06:52 
IP2 host2 data 05/04/2019 at 11:07:15

Comment: A: IP  Hostname Status Updated On Comment
IP1 host1 data 05/04/2019 at 11:06:52 This is a device
IP2 host2 data 05/04/2019 at 11:07:15 This is a device